# I'd like to have the same design with my background-color circle using bootstrap 5 when i will pass on mobile size

Tags: css, mdbootstrap

I'm designing a card with a color background instead of image, after passing in mobile size (sm or xs) my rounded-circle background-color changes to an ellipsoid's one.

Here is what I want:

[image: here what I want]

I would like to have the same design for xl-md-sm even for xs, I used @mediaquery to try to resolve this problem unfortunately it didn't work. so I want your help.

This is what I get:

[image: this is what I get]

Here is HTML markup:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-4 px-5">
<div class="card ">
  <div class="row mt-5 w-100 hover-shadow ">
    <div class="meq card-body bg-danger .d-sm-flex col-2 mt-0 mb-0 rounded-circle px-sm-0 ">
      <h1 class="nowrap text-center text-light font-weight-bold px-sm-2 py-5">KKE</h1>
      <a href="#!">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 second_part">
      <div class="card-text justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item-action">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
              <h3 class="mb-1 text-dark font-weight-bold">Kumbu<br> Kumbu<br>Ezechias</h3>
              <small class="text-muted">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li>
                    <div class="progress ">
                      <div class=" progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;"
                        aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li> Dear you won</li>
                  <li><small class="font-weight-bold align-content-center float-right">Mo 20224525</small>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </small>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">
              Xxxxx77
            </p>
            <p class="mb-1">
              04:25
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/ card 1 -->
```

here is CSS

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  initial-letter-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h3,
h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  margin-left: -10px;
  padding-left: -10px;
  list-style: none;
}
h6 {
  text-align: end;
  margin-top: 70%;
  margin-right: 37%;
}
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (max-width: 48em) {
  h1,
  h3 {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-top: 0%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  div .meq {
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 10.1rem;
    max-width: 10.1rem;
    padding-left: 0.7rem;
    padding-right: 1.9rem;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    initial-letter-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your Css ? so that we can check what's wrong

Comment: have you tried `.rounded-circle` class of boostrap?

Comment: yes, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's making the trouble is when you use classes `.d-sm-flex` and `card-body` that are making trouble.
Here is what I suggest you for your circle `div`

```
<div class="rounded-circle text-center" style="width: 10rem; height: 10rem; background: red;" >
      <h1 class="nowrap text-center text-light font-weight-bold px-sm-2 py-5">KKE</h1>
      <a href="#!">
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You mean you want the same behaviour like `col` class? right?

Comment: I suggest that you use a rounded image(something like a logo)

Comment: it no what i want to obtain as final result